# Separate pubspec.yaml file based on flavor

Tags: flutter

I have an app where I should launch it in two versions, one for china and one global
I created flavors and everything but my problem is that I want to separate the pubspec.yaml file into two files based on flavor, because the libraries in china are different from the global and I don't want to build including all the libraries for the two versions

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a current limitation of Flutter, cf [#46979](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46979).